# SQL server query, select first date where enough stock

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have a table like this :

```
id  Date                    Qty
1   Feb 25 2015 12:00AM      34
2   Feb 27 2015 12:00AM      34
3   Mar 17 2015 12:00AM      153
4   Mar 27 2015 12:00AM      68
5   Apr  3 2015 12:00AM      153
6   May  6 2015 12:00AM      153
```

I want select the first date where I will have enough Qty for my need.
I made this request that works for most of the case, but not on this data when I have a need of 210. It should select me MAR 17, but I have Feb 27

```
SELECT top 1
T1.Date,
T1.Qty
,SUM(cast (T2.Qty as int)) AS cumulqte
FROM
  ##temptest3 T1
    INNER JOIN ##temptest3 T2
        ON T1.Date >= T2.Date
GROUP BY T1.id, T1.Date, T1.Qty
HAVING SUM(cast (T2.Qty as int)) >=210
ORDER BY T1.Date;
```

I have try to change the order by and a lot of things, but nothing work.

Edit : 
This is the way I create my table :

```
select * into ##temptest1 from sysadm.fnSplitString('17223ü17225ü17243ü17253ü17260ü17293','ü')
update ##temptest1 set splitdata=DATEADD(day,cast(splitdata as int), '1967-12-31');

select * into ##temptest2 from sysadm.fnSplitString('34ü34ü153ü68ü153ü153','ü')
update ##temptest2 set splitdata='0' where splitdata=''

create table ##temptest3 (id int,Date nvarchar(max), Qte NVARCHAR(MAX) )
INSERT INTO ##temptest3 (id, Qte, Date) select ##temptest2.id, ##temptest2.splitdata, ##temptest1.splitdata from ##temptest2 inner join ##temptest1 on ##temptest2.id=##temptest1.id
```

Comment: what version of sql server?

Comment: I use SQL server 2008. It work for me to when I use your code. The bug I maybe cause by the whay I create my table. I will edit my post to show you

Comment: jpw, when I use your query I have a incorrect syntax near order

Comment: Looking at your table creation you're using NVARCHAR for the date. You need to convert this to a Date / datetime or the order won't work properly

Comment: @Christian Barron, you are right, it was because I was using nvarchar. I change it to date and it works. I was searching for the wrong problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that when you create your ##temp tables you're using the `nvarchar` type instead of `datetime` (and `int` for qty). The best remedy would be to use the correct types when you create the tables, if that won't work you can use casts in the query like this:

```
SELECT top 1
cast(t1.Date as  datetime),
T1.Qty
,SUM(cast (T2.Qty as int)) AS cumulqte
FROM
  ##temptest3 T1
    INNER JOIN ##temptest3 T2
        ON cast(t1.Date as  datetime) >= cast(t2.Date as  datetime)
GROUP BY T1.id, cast(t1.Date as  datetime), T1.Qty
HAVING SUM(cast (T2.Qty as int)) >=210
ORDER BY cast(t1.Date as  datetime);
```

See this [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/df187/1)

Answer (score 1):

As I said in my comment you need to cast / convert your Date field to a date or datetime for the ordering to work properly:

```
SELECT top 1
T1.Date,
T1.Qty
,SUM(cast (T2.Qty as int)) AS cumulqte
FROM
  ##temptest3 T1
    INNER JOIN ##temptest3 T2
        ON T1.Date >= T2.Date
GROUP BY T1.id, T1.Date, T1.Qty
HAVING SUM(cast (T2.Qty as int)) >=210
ORDER BY Cast(T1.Date as datetime)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
DECLARE @TEMP_COMMUNICATION_TABLE TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1), [DATE] DATETIME, QTY INT)
INSERT INTO @TEMP_COMMUNICATION_TABLE VALUES ('2015-02-27',34),('2015-02-25',34),('2015-03-17',153),('2015-03-27',68),('2015-04-03',153),('2015-05-06',153)

--SELECT * FROM @TEMP_COMMUNICATION_TABLE
DECLARE @INPUT INT = 210

SELECT TOP 1
    T1.Date,
    T1.Qty,
    SUM(T2.QTY)
FROM @TEMP_COMMUNICATION_TABLE T1
INNER JOIN @TEMP_COMMUNICATION_TABLE  T2
    ON T1.DATE >= T2.DATE
GROUP BY
    T1.Date,
    T1.Qty
HAVING SUM(cast (T2.Qty as int)) >=@INPUT
--ORDER BY T1.Date;
```

Your query is perfect,remove order by.